# Appending URL parameter at every request only if parameter already exists to save opt-out option responsive design

Tags: php, wordpress, url, parameters

I have a responsive Wordpress site: www.2eenheid.de. My client wants an option on a mobile to view the site in fullsize, an opt-out responsive option. Now, I found this solution:

http://css-tricks.com/user-opt-out-responsive-design/

Which uses PHP to remove the `meta name="viewport"` tag when the URL parameter `?resp=no` (URL becomes: www.2eenheid.de/?resp=no) is called. By removing the `meta name="viewport"` tag the site becomes fullsize on mobile. See code below:

```
<head>

   <title>My cool site huzzah</title>

   <?php
     if (!$_GET['resp'] == 'no') { ?>
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
   <?php } ?>

</head>

<body class="<?php if (!$_GET['resp'] == 'no') { echo "resp"; } ?>">
```

This changes the current page to fullsize, but if I click a different link it changes back to responsive, which is logical because the link doesn't contain the parameter `?resp=no` anymore.

Now my client has the requirement that if a user wants the fullsize website, it needs to stay fullsize even after clicking a different URL until a user changes it back to responsive.

So my question is how can i save the `?resp=no` parameter once clicked for every URL request, until a user changes it back to responsive by e.g. clicking a different link (maybe with a different parameter)?

I've tried googling but I can't find any good solutions. I've seen people suggesting session values but I find that very hard to understand and some people say that thats not good practice because session values are used for logins.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

**EDIT 3:**
The suggestion below seems good, but I'm quite new to PHP sessions. I changed my code with the suggestion below to this:

```
<?php ini_set('display_errors', true);

session_start(); 
if(isset($_REQUEST['resp'])) {
    $_SESSION['resp'] = boolval($_REQUEST['resp']);
}

// Check if enabled
$enabled = isset($_SESSION['resp']) && $_SESSION['resp'];


?><!DOCTYPE html>

<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />

<?php if($enabled): ?>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<?php endif; ?>

<title>LALALA</title>

</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?> id="<?php if(isset($_SESSION['resp']) && $_SESSION['resp']) { echo "resp"; } ?>">
```

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: try to set the cookie once the user has click, and check for cookie each time..

Comment: You need to remove the `<?php ?>` tags before the doctype. The way you wrote is adds a '\n' (new line) character which causes problem using IE and HTML5 (google for BOM).

Comment: @Virus721 : I changed it, however it still doesnt work. Is it supposed to work when I call the URL parameter ?resp ?

Comment: You still have a whitespace before your first <?php tag

Comment: @Virus721: oops, i added an extra space by accident here. On my website www.2eenheid.de it doesnt have this space. Can't seem to get it to work though.. any ideas?

Comment: See my new comment under my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
session_start();

// ...

if(isset($_REQUEST['resp'])) {
    $_SESSION['resp'] = boolval($_REQUEST['resp']);
}
```

And :

```
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['resp']) && $_SESSION['resp']): ?>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<?php endif; ?>
```

You could probably use cookies too as said in a comment, but i never looked how it works.

EDIT : An example :

```
<?php

// If the parameter is in the URL, enable/disable (else leave as it currently is).
if(isset($_REQUEST['enableMode'])) {
    $_SESSION['enableMode'] = boolval($_REQUEST['enableMode']);
}

// Check if enabled
$enabled = isset($_SESSION['enableMode']) && $_SESSION['enableMode'];

?>

<?php if($enabled): ?>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<?php endif; ?>

<a href="index.php?enableMode=1">Enable mode</a>
<a href="index.php?enableMode=0">Disable mode</a>
<a href="index.php">Change page without changing anything</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response @Virus721. I'm not quite familiar with PHP Sessions. Could you explain how the first code works exactly? Do I use `<?php session_start(); ?>` before the HTML tag for this to work?

Comment: `session_start()` makes the variable `$_SESSION` available. `$_SESSION`'s value is persitent between requests. If you want to access it, you first have to make it available by calling `session_start()`, then you can use it. `session_start()` has to be called in every request where you want to use `$_SESSION`.

Comment: thank you. I added my code as an edit above, cus I can't seem to get it working. Could you please check what i did wrong?

Comment: Did you forget to change `if(!$_GET['resp'] == 'no')` to `if(isset($_SESSION['resp']) && $_SESSION['resp'])` or is it what you want to do ?

Comment: I forgot. I changed it to `<body <?php body_class(); ?> id="<?php if(isset($_SESSION['resp']) && $_SESSION['resp']) { echo "resp"; } ?>">`. It doesn't work though. Is it supposed to do something when I call the URL "www.2eenheid.de/?resp"? When I view the source code of that URL it removes everything after the 'session_start'.

Comment: This code you now have is supposed to set the index `resp` in the array `$_SESSION` to true if the parameter `resp` is present in the URL and if it can be evaluated to true. For example,you can have the links, one to active, and one to deactivate this resp mode : `<a href="index.php?resp=1">Activate</a><a href="index.php?resp=0">Deactivate</a><a href="index.php">Change page without changing the current mode</a>`

Comment: When I try this: http://www.2eenheid.de/supportenbeheer/?resp=1 I get a server error. It is because I use permalinks?

Comment: I don't see the error message in my crystal ball, can you paste it ? ^^

Comment: When I click http://www.2eenheid.de/?resp=1 i just get a server error. No message or website..

Comment: Blank pages without error messages often happen when a include fails because the page you're trying to include has a syntax error. Have you added `ini_set('display_errors', true);` at the very beginning of your script to make sure errors are displayed ?

Comment: I modified my code to what you suggested in your edit (see my EDIT 3 above). Also just added ini_set error thingy. I get this error: `Fatal error: Call to undefined function boolval() in C:\srvdata\WWW\2eenheid\2eenheid.de\wp-content\themes\2eenheid\header.php on line 5`

Comment: Ho well, i guess i mispelled that function name, or maybe invented it... Try a cast to (bool) instead

Comment: Ah! Thanks for your help. I used `$_SESSION['resp'] = (bool)($_REQUEST['resp'] == true);` Works now, but on mobile its kind of weird... It shows my site SOMETIMES in responsive mode, sometimes not. I don't get it???

Comment: When I request http://www.2eenheid.de/?resp=1 it goes responsive (on mobile). But it doesn't save this setting for other pages and that is what I was looking for.. :(

Comment: I thought maybe the rpoblem is at setting it to "true" hardcoded. So I changed to: `$_SESSION['resp'] = (bool)($_REQUEST['resp']);` but still same effect..

Answer (score 0):

Usings sessions for this is too much, a better mechanish exists, called "output_add_rewrite_var". Using this system, we can say the following:

```
<?php if(!isset($_GET['resp'])): ?>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<?php else:
    output_add_rewrite_var("resp", "1");
endif; ?>
```

The above code fits perfectly in the view place of a MVC system, since it is a view specific option. The code works by looking if `$_GET['resp']` exists or not, and depending on that, if it exists, calling `output_add_rewrite_var("resp", "1");` to put itself in other url's, and if it doesn't exists, it adds the meta tag.